# UpdateView form pre-populate error

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I am having problems while updating a image details using UpdateView.
The image details are been saved successfully but while updating/editing the details, the form fields are displaying empty.
The expected scenario is to have the forms field pre-populated with the existing values when edit option is triggered.

My code :

```
models.py

from photologue.models import Photo
class PhotoContent(Photo) :
    user  = models.ForeignKey(User)


forms.py

class SiteAccessForm(forms.Form) :

    access_key = forms.CharField(required = True, label = "Website Access Key",
        max_length = 10)


class PhotoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = PhotoContent
        fields = ('image', 'title', 'caption', 'crop_from',)


views.py


class GalleryListView(CookieMixin, FormMixin, PhotoListView) :

    model = PhotoContent
    form_class = SiteAccessForm
    paginate_by = 20

    def get_success_url(self):
        username    = self.kwargs['username']
        return reverse("photo_list", kwargs={"username" : str(username)})

    def get_template_names(self):
        username = self.kwargs['username']
        if Theme.objects.filter(user__username=username).exists() :
            theme_selected = Theme.objects.filter(user__username=username)
            template_name = 'themes/%s/photologue/photo_list.html' % (theme_selected.values()[0]['name'])
        else :
            template_name = 'themes/default/photologue/photo_list.html'
        return [template_name]

    def get_queryset(self) :
        username = self.kwargs['username']
        queryset = PhotoContent.objects.filter(user__username=username)
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(GalleryListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        logged_user = self.request.user
        username    = self.kwargs['username']

        context['object_list_len'] = len(PhotoContent.objects.filter(user__username=username))
        context['page_list']       = Page.objects.filter(user__username=username)
        context['access_key']  = UserProfile.objects.filter(user__username=username).values()[0]['access_key']
        context['site_url']    = Site.objects.get_current()

        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form       = self.get_form(form_class)
        context['form'] = form

        if 'access_granted' in self.request.COOKIES :
            context['access_granted'] = self.request.COOKIES['access_granted']
        else :
            context['access_granted'] = 'False'

        context['username']     = username

        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        self.request.COOKIES.get('access_granted', 'False')

        if form.is_valid():
            user_access_key = form.cleaned_data['access_key']
            username   = self.kwargs['username']
            access_key = UserProfile.objects.filter(user__username=username).values()[0]['access_key']

            if user_access_key != access_key :
                return self.form_invalid(form)

            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.add_cookie('access_granted', 'True', max_age=3600)
        return super(GalleryListView, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        error = "Incorrect Access Key provided. Try again !!"
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form, error=error))

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        response = super(GalleryListView, self).render_to_response(context, **response_kwargs)
        if 'access_granted' not in self.request.COOKIES :
            response.set_cookie("access_granted", "False")
        return response



class PhotoUpdateView(UpdateView) :

    model = PhotoContent
    form_class = PhotoForm

    def get_template_names(self):
        if Theme.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).exists() :
            theme_selected = Theme.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
            template_name = 'themes/%s/photologue/photo_form.html' % (theme_selected.values()[0]['name'])
        else :
            template_name = 'themes/default/photologue/photo_form.html'
        return [template_name]

    def get_queryset(self) :
        queryset = PhotoContent.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PhotoUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['username'] = self.kwargs['username']
        context['logged_user'] = self.request.user
        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('photo_list', kwargs={"username" : str(self.request.user)} )



photo_list.html

{% extends "themes/default/index.html" %}
{% load url from future %}

{% block content %}
    <h1 class="page-header">Photo Album</h1>
    {% if object_list %}
        {% for photo in object_list %}
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 thumb body_color">
                <a class='href_color' href="{% url 'photo_detail' username=username pk=photo.pk %}">
                    <img src="{{ photo.get_thumbnail_url }}" alt="{{ photo.title }}"/><br>
                    {{photo.title}}
                    {% if logged_user == username %}
                        <form method="post" action="{% url 'photo_update' username=username pk=photo.pk %}">
                            {% csrf_token %}

                            <!-- When this button is clicked, it opens an empty form -->

                            <input type="submit" value="Edit Photo" class="btn btn-primary">
                        </form>
                        <form method="post" action="{% url 'photo_delete' username=username pk=photo.pk %}">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <input type="submit" value="Delete Photo" class="btn btn-primary">
                        </form>
                    {% endif %}
                </a>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <h3>No Photos are available.</h3>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}



photo_form.html


{% extends "themes/default/index.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}
    <a href="{% url 'photo_list' username=logged_user.username %}"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Back</button></a><br>
    <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <br>
        {% for field in form %}
            <div class='form_content_color'>
                {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
                {{ field }}<br><br>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
<body>
</body>
</html>


urls.py

url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w\d]+)/photo-album$', GalleryListView.as_view(), name='photo_list'),
url(r'^photo/edit/(?P<username>[-\w\d]+)/(?P<pk>[\d]+)$', auth(PhotoUpdateView.as_view()), name='photo_update'),
```

Any help/suggestions will be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to inspect in debug `PhotoUpdateView` `get_context_data` second line `context['form']` or simply `print` it?

Comment: I have already tried the below :


    http://pastebin.com/XDMHivNK

and I am getting the Photoform only in the template but with empty fields and an Error that Title field is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved !!

I was making a mistake of using 'POST' method in the Edit Link.

```
<form method='post' action="{% url 'photo_update' username=username pk=photo.pk %}">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <input type="submit" value="Edit Photo" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

changed to

```
<form action="{% url 'photo_update' username=username pk=photo.pk %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Edit Photo" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```